# Tkinter - tracing a list

Tags: python, tkinter

I am trying to use trace to control the user values that get entered into an Entry widget. I have a list of size 23. I have other lists that I am using trace successfully on, but they are a bit smaller (size of 4).

```
        def limit_10(*args):
            for i in skills:
                val = i.get()
                if not val.isnumeric():
                    val = ''.join(filter(str.isnumeric, val))
                    i.set(val)
                elif val.isnumeric():
                    if int(val) > 10:
                        i.set(10)
                    else:
                        i.set(val)
```

Here I declare my list:

```
        for _ in SKILLS:
            i = StringVar()
            i.trace('w', limit_10)
            skills.append(i)
```

When I run the program having set the trace, what happens is that the program doesn't startup.

However, if I stop tracing my list of size 23, everything works fine. I am most certain that my problem comes from poor implementation - the for loop in the callback function. However, I can't find a better solution for retrieving a value from a list...

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: You are calling `.set()` on *all* of the vars in the list, not just the one that triggered the trace.  That one is perfectly safe (the trace is temporarily disabled while the trace function is running, to avoid an infinite recursion), but all of the others result in calling `.set()` on *all* of the vars in the list, not just the one that triggered the trace...

Answer (score 0):

Never mind, I solved this on my own. Changed my list assigning function to:

```
for _ in SKILLS:
    i = StringVar()
    i.trace('w', partial(limit_10, i))
    skills.append(i)
```

and my callback function to:

```
def limit_10(i, *args):
    val = i.get()
    if not val.isnumeric():
        val = ''.join(filter(str.isnumeric, val))
        i.set(val)
    elif val.isnumeric():
        if int(val) > 10:
            i.set(10)
        else:
            i.set(val)
```

and everything works fine.